# Text size getting smaller for same div in forreach loop

Tags: html, css, ejs

I have this code

```html
  <div class="bounties">
    <% projects.forEach(function(project) { %>
  
    <section class="box" style="margin: 1rem;">
      <a href="/project/<%=project.UniqueID%>">
      <article class="media" style="background: white;">
        <div class="media-content">
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              <span style="font-size: 2rem; color: #2d2d2d;margin-left: -2px;">Earn <strong
                  style="color: #5cb85c">$<%=project.DollarAmount.toLocaleString()%>!</strong></span>
              <br>
              <span><small><i class="fa-solid fa-clock" style="margin-right: 0.2rem;"></i> Listed <%= getTimePassed(project.ListedDate) %>
                <% if(project.Status == 'open') { %>
                  <div class="status regular tag" style=""><p style="color:black">Open</p></div>
                <% } else if(project.Status == 'claimed') { %>  
                  <div class="status claimed tag">Claimed</div>
                <% } else if(project.Status == 'closed') { %>  
                  <div class="status closed tag">Closed</div>
                <% } else if(project.Status == 'cancelled') { %>  
                  <div class="status closed tag">Cancelled</div>
                <% } else if(project.Status == 'completed') { %>  
                  <div class="status claimed tag">Completed</div> 
                <% } %>
  
<style>
                        .status.regular {
      font-size: 12px;
      height: fit-content;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      border-radius: 16px;
      background-color: lightblue;
      font-weight: 400;
      opacity: 1;
      font-weight: 400;
      color:black

    }
    .tags {
      display: flex;
      gap: 8px;
    }

    .tag {
      
      border-radius: 16px;
      background-color: #ffc6c2;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #690D0D;
      background-color: #690D0D;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      transition: .4s border-color;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .tag:hover {
      border-color: #bb7676;
    }


    .tag,
    .status,
    .edit,
    .delete {
      padding: 8px 12px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .status.closed {
      font-size: 12px;
      height: fit-content;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      background-color: #FFCCCB;
      border-radius: 16px;
    }
    .status.claimed {
      font-size: 12px;
      height: fit-content;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      border-radius: 16px;
    }

                  </style>
               
              <h3>              <%=project.Title%>
              </h5>
              <%=project.Description%>
            </p>

          </div>
          <% project.Tags.forEach(function(tag) { %>
            <div class="tag"><%= tag %></div>
          <% }); %>



          <nav class="level is-mobile">
            <div class="level-left"><small>
               

                  
                  <button
                  style="border-radius: 5px;"
                  class="button bot_right is-small bountybutton has-text-black">View More</button>
              </small></div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </article>
    </a>
    </section>
    <% }); %> 

  </div>
```

I have this code that renders the projects for each in ejs. however, as the projects continue on the page displayed, text size in the boxes become smaller and smaller. Why is this happening?

The overall div becomes smaller, and I am not sure why.

Here is the CSS code for this.

```css
  .box {
    position: relative !important;
    margin-bottom: 56px !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    transition: .4s;
    
  }

  .bounties>.box {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .bounties>.box:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
    filter: brightness(98%);
    transform: translateY(-2px);
  }
```

Here is an example
[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you used your browser devtools to inspect exactly where/how the css/HTML is being applied? Especially look at that use of HTML small element.

Comment: You have an unclosed small tag so the font size gets smaller by 1px each time. Putting your code through a validator should have found this.